# Postgres SQL Database consuming all space in hard disk

Tags: database, postgresql, centos, hard-drive

I have a serious problem with a postgres 8.3 database running on CentOs, a closed service use this database to store analog variables on a especific table from 5 and 5 minutes about 2 years, this information is precious from my company.

A nice day the postgres process stopped and the Hard drive from server was full. We order more 2 compatible hd with the server, it will take 30 days to arrive, but the application have to work until this drives arrive.

Today the application insert around 400 MB per day on Database.

I just symlinked some folders to a external 1 TB HD USB 2.0.

The actual situation is:

```
df -h

Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     ext4    1010G  1009G 224M 100% /
/dev/sda2     ext4     99M   17M   78M  18% /boot
```

and the $PGDATA folder have

```
/var/pgsql/data  1005G
```

The main table have aroud 600GB.

I just make a Backup.tar from the database and delete a lot of older rows, and trying run the VACUUM command, on the middle of process a error about disk space occurs and don't finish the VACUUM.

I've already tried run VACUUM, REINDEX, CLUSTER, and I have the same error.

I'm thinking on DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE, it's the best option? free the disk space??

Someone have a tip or a solution for this case?

Thanks, and sorry for the english.

Comment: Show the exact commands run, exact error message (edit the question to add). Instead of symlinking, use a tablespace and alter table to move tables to the tablespace. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html . Also, you're on an ancient and unsupported version, start planning your upgrade.

Comment: I hope you made the backup including *all* files, while the database server was stopped. Or followed the online backup procedure with `pg_start_backup` and `pg_stop_backup.`

Comment: as Craig Ringer said `create tablespace new location '/absolute/path/to/directory/on/new/drive';` and then `alter table table_name set tablespace new;` keep in mind that Postgres will lock the whole table for this process to complete.

Comment: I'm nephew on the company, and they don't maked any mantince on DB in the past.
@CraigRinger The server run's offline and the error message don't was saved, Thanks for the tip about tablespaces! The application have a old Postgres client and I need see the compatibility with the application.
I used the PgAdmin to make the Backup.

Comment: Tablespaces are completely application-transparent. The app would have to go far out of its way to even notice that they were in use. To use tablespaces you'll have to be able to free enough disk space from somewhere for the server to be able to start up and write a little bit of WAL.

Comment: I got it run the VACUUM with any argument. I will wait the process done.